# Auto deduction for const class member

Tags: c++, c++14, auto

What are the differences between the following two implementations for accessing a private constant class member?

```
// Auto& (compile ok)
class Foo {
  private:
    const int _foo;
  public:
    Foo(const int& in) : _foo(in) {}
    auto& foo() { return _foo; }
}

// Explicit type (compiler error)
class Foo {
  private:
    const int _foo;
  public:
    Foo(const int& in) : _foo(in) {}
    int& foo() { return _foo; }
}
```

With `auto` the compiler does not complain but the explicit `int` type declaration in fact gives compiler error (which is due to the constness). In this case, what is `auto` deduced?

Comment: Sidenote: Be sure you know what you're doing w.r.t. semantics when using const references.  See [int vs const int&](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4705871/211160).  And notice it could well be slower than returning an int.

Answer (score 4):

Since `_foo` is of type `const int`, `auto` refers to `const int`. Change your 'Explicit type' code to return `const int&` and the compiler should not complain anymore.