# Returning a vector by value into a reference

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
std::vector<Info*> filter(int direction)
{
    std::vector<Info*> new_buffer;
    for(std::vector<Info*>::iterator it=m_Buffer.begin();it<m_Buffer.end();it++)
    {
        if(((*it)->direction == direction)
        {
            new_buffer.push_back(*it);
        }
    }

    return new_buffer;
}

std::vector<Info*> &filteredInfo= filter(m_Direction);
```

Can someone explain what is happening here ? Would the filter method return by value create a temporary and filteredInfo never gets destroyed because its a reference ?

Not sure if I understand correctly. What is the diference between filteredInfo being a reference and not being one in this case ?

Comment: Does this compile?  If it does are you using MSVS?

Comment: Yes, its Visual Studio 2005

Comment: OK.  Do note that this is non-standard code.  MSVS allows this but this will not work on most other compilers.

Comment: Provide a [MCVE] please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your compiler should complain of that code.

This statement:

```
std::vector<Info*> &filteredInfo= filter(m_Direction);
```

is a bad idea where `filter` is:

```
std::vector<Info*> filter(int direction);
```

You are trying to create a reference to a temporary object. Even if it succeeds with your compiler, its illegal.

You should use:

```
std::vector<Info*> filteredInfo= filter(m_Direction);
```

Its as efficient as you want. Either a `move` operation (C++11) will happen there or [Return Value Optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization) will kick in. For your implementation of `filter`, it should be RVO on optimized builds *(it depends on your compiler quality though)* .

However, you should note that you are copying raw pointers into your vector, I hope you have a correct ownership model? If not, I advice you to use a smart pointer.

Comment: Can this cause a memory leak ? when using the reference to a temporary ?

Comment: @Kobe Not a memory leak but certainly UB if you use that reference.

Comment: MSVC (Visual Studio) does something well define here, but it is indeed compiler dependant and not standards comformant

Answer (score 2):

Here is what happens:

1. `std::vector<Info*> new_buffer;` creates an object locally.
2. `return new_buffer;` moves `new_buffer` to a temporary object when `filter(m_Direction)` is called.
3. Now if you call `std::vector<Info*> filteredInfo= filter(m_Direction);` the temprary object will be moved to `filteredInfo` so there is no unnecessary copies and it's the most efficient way.
4. But, if you call `std::vector<Info*> &filteredInfo= filter(m_Direction);` then `filteredInfo` is bound to a temporary object, which is a terrible idea and most compilers will complain about this.

Answer (score 2):

Here you're correctly puzzled because there are two independent weird facts mixing in:

- Your compiler allows a non-const reference to be bound to a temporary. This historically was a mistake in Microsoft compilers and is not permitted by the standard. That code should not compile.
- The standard however, strangely enough, actually allows binding `const` references to temporaries and has a special rule for that: the temporary object will not be destroyed immediately (like it would happen normally) but its life will be extended to the life of the reference.

In code:

```
std::vector<int> foo() {
    std::vector<int> x{1,2,3};
    return x;
}

int main() {
    const std::vector<int>& x = foo(); // legal
    for (auto& item : x) {
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The reason for this apparently absurd rule about binding const references to temporaries is that in C++ there is a very common "pattern"(1) of passing const references instead of values for parameters, even when identity is irrelevant. If you combine this (anti)-pattern with implicit conversion what happens is that for example:

```
void foo(const std::string& x) { ... }
```

wouldn't be callable with

```
foo("Hey, you");
```

without the special rule, because the `const char *` (literal) is implicitly converted to a temporary `std::string` and passed as parameter bound to a const reference.

(1) The pattern is indeed quite bad from a philosophical point of view because a value is a value and a reference is a reference: the two are logically distinct concepts. [A const reference is **not** a value and confusing the two can be the source of very subtle bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4705871/320726). C++ however is performance-obsessed and, especially before move semantics, passing const references was considered a "smart" way of passing values, despite being a problem because of lifetime and aliasing issues and for making things harder for the optimizer. With a modern compiler passing a reference should be used only for "big" objects, especially ones that are **not** constructed on the fly to be passed or when you're actually interested in object identity and not in just object value.