# const auto& to integer with std::min std::max

Tags: c++, c++11

I have these codes below. What's wrong with the `const auto&` in this context, it caused unexpected outputs.

It works fine while compiled with gcc-4.8.5, but gets unexpected outputs with gcc-4.9.2.

If I remove the `&` in `const auto&`, it works fine with both gcc versions.

```cpp
// max_dim is a protobuf filed: const auto max_dim = msg.max();
// cat2_num is an element in std::vector<int32_t>: const auto cat2_num = vec[i]
const auto& res_num = std::max(1, std::min(max_dim, cat2_num));
LOG(ERROR) << res_num << ", " << max_dim << ", " << cat2_num
   << ", " << std::max(1, std::min(max_dim, cat2_num));
```

outputs:

```
 -1392522416, 3, 1, 1
 2, 3, 2, 2
 3, 3, 3, 3
 -1392522416, 3, 1, 1
 3, 3, 6, 3
 2, 3, 2, 2
 -1392522416, 3, 1, 1
 -1392522416, 3, 1, 1
 2, 3, 2, 2
```

=========== updated ========

I couldn't reproduce the undefined behavior with these codes:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int32_t> v = {-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 6};
    const int a = 3;
    const auto& b = a;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        const auto& c = v[i];
        const auto& d = std::max(1, std::min(b, c));
        std::cout << d << ", " << b << ", " << c << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
1, 3, -1
1, 3, 0
1, 3, 1
2, 3, 2
3, 3, 3
3, 3, 6
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: You have dangling reference to prvalue 1 - it means, that you have a reference to a temporary integer. It is valid until the nearest sequence point (semicolon here). So this reference points to "nowhere" when you try to access a value. When you use `const auto` the value returned from `std::max` will be copied and you can use it normally

Comment: @GeorgyFirsov Temporaries are valid until the end of a full-expression, which can contain multiple sequence points.

Comment: @aschepler, my mistake, I aggree with you

Comment: Re: "I couldn't reproduce the undefined behavior" -- "undefined behavior" means **only** that the language definition does not tell you what the program does. It does not mean that something bad will happen.

Comment: Stepanov covers the design and issues of `std::min` and `std::max` in his [Efficient Programming with Components](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLHxtyCq_WDLXryyw91lahwdtpZsmo4BGD) lectures.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior.  In

```
const auto& res_num = std::max(1, std::min(max_dim, cat2_num));
```

The `1` is a prvalue, so a temporary integer is created that gets bound to the function parameter.  This would be okay of max was like

```
template <typename T> const T max(const T&, const T&);
```

but instead it is defined like

```
template <typename T> const T& max(const T&, const T&);
```

So, if that `1` happens to be the maximum value, then `max` returns to you a reference to that temporary object that was created.  After that, the temporary object is destroyed<sup>1</sup>, leaving `res_num` as a dangling reference.  To fix the code make `res_num` a non-reference like

```
const auto res_num = std::max(1, std::min(max_dim, cat2_num));
```

and now you get a copy of the correct value.

<sup>1: all temporaries are destroyed at the end of the full expression the are created in</sup>

Comment: Maybe a bit clearer if you also note the signature of `std::max` is `template <typename T> const T& max(const T&, const T&);`

Comment: Since it's a const reference, wouldn't the lifetime of the temporary get extended?

Comment: @cigien No.  Lifetime extension is not passed through functions.  You only get lifetime extension when you assign a prvalue to a function local `const T&` or a `T&&`.  The return of `max` is not a prvalue, so no lifetime extension.

Comment: @aschepler, in this case it is even clearer to note some type inference rules for `auto` - it throws away cv-qualifiers an references. So `const auto = std::max(...)` will have `const int32_t` type (as I understand author uses `int32_t` here), because the reference was thrown away by `auto`

Comment: @aschepler I've added that in.

Comment: "function local" is not necessary. Temporary lifetime extension can also apply to references at namespace scope or static class members.

Comment: Cool.  But I couldn't reproduce the undefined behavior with buggy codes, as I updated in the question.

Comment: @RoyHuang The "fun" thing about undefined behavior is that the expected result is also part of the set of results that the program can have.  As you can see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1400ddb7f61a4ef), I get different results.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks. I have [reproduced it too](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b7b5dafb5499f82e)。 And I have tested that it has nothing to do with gcc version, I reproduced it with both gcc-4.8 and gcc-4.9. The only cause is just as you clarified.

Answer (score 0):

@NathanOliver has given clear declaration for the cause. Here is some other related infomation.

1. `const T&` is helpful for large objects, but it involves `lifetime` and `aliasing` problem. So be careful.
2. For `int`, `double`, `pointers` values, `const T&` gains nothing. In this situation, `copy` is cheaper than `reference`.

reference: [int vs const int&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705593/int-vs-const-int)